# c++ CString Tokenize strange issue

Tags: c++, mfc

I observed a strange issue but am not able to figure out why this is happening. Any inputs on this greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
CString strValue;
strValue = "99\tStop\t";

CString strToken;
int pos = 2;
strToken = strValue.Tokenize(_T("\t"), pos);

cout << strToken;
```

This will return me "Stop" which is correct (please note the line has a tab separator for each entry)

However, for an input

```
strValue = "100\tStart\t"
```

The strToken returned is "0".

Any ideas about this?

Comment: I don't quite understand even why the 1st example worked. `strValue = "99  Stop    ";` does not look like having any `\t`. Even if you say so, it really does not look like it. Why not write explicitly `"100\tStart\t"` and check it? Maybe source code formatting was strange and in one case it was actually a [tab] and in the other it was just spaces.

Comment: @luk32, The code I have shared is a test code but the input string are from a file where I am reading. I am using notepad++ which shows me a tab. Anyways, I tried input "100\tStart\t" and "99\tStart\t". It still shows the same problem for 100 but works for 99.

Comment: Then maybe make an example that actually reproduces the problem, and be sure it does. Now it looks like you introduced new problems in making up an example. Post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Edit: ok. That is something.

Comment: @luk32, I tried with "100\tStart\t" and "99\tStart\t". The input 100 has a problem where as 99 does not.

Comment: I guess now I understand the reason behind this. The variable "pos" is the problem. Currently it is set to 2, so it is starting after 2 numbers "99" but when i set it to "100", it returns me 0 as there is a tab after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Err... ok. I think what you observe is expected. After reading this [Tokenize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4ftfkd2.aspx).

Esp this part : `CStringT Tokenize( PCXSTR pszTokens, int& iStart ) const;` [...] "*On each call to Tokenize the function starts at iStart, skips leading delimiters, and returns a CStringT object containing the current token, which is the string of characters up to the next delimiter character.*"

You start at position 2.

```
"99  Stop    "
"100  Start  "
 012  <-- pos
```

In the 1st case for `pos = 2` you start at `\t` and ignore all the leading delimiters and returns the string till the next one, which is `Stop`. In the 2nd case, you start at `0`, and the next character is a specified delimiter, thus you get string from `pos = 2` till `\t`, it is only one character `0`.

Mystery solved.

Comment: Yes.. I will mark yours as answer. Thanks for helping me out.